# ESXi 8.0 host not detecting USB devices

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I've got an ESXi 8.0.1 production host (Dell PowerEdge R450) that I'm trying to attach a USB device to.  I've tried a USB external HDD as well as a USB licensing dongle.  These devices have been plugged into a Windows laptop and are confirmed working.

I've restarted the USB Arbitrator service and the host.d service, plugged the device in with the usb arbitrator service stopped, but lsusb only lists the onboard USB controllers either way.

These commands also come up empty:

esxcli hardware usb passthrough device list
cat /var/log/vmkernel.log | grep -i usb 
cat /var/log/vmkernel.log | grep -i USB

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!